# Measuring text width in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, text

Using the Qt framework, how do I measure the width (in pixels) of a piece of text rendered with a given font/style?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since Qt 5.11 you must use [`horizontalAdvance()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#horizontalAdvance) method of [`QFontMetrics`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html) class instead of `width()`. [`width()` is now obselete.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics-obsolete.html#width)

```
QFont myFont(fontName, fontSize);;
QString str("I wonder how wide this is?");

QFontMetrics fm(myFont);
int width=fm.horizontalAdvance(str);
```

Answer (score 82):

You can use [QFontMetrics](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html) class - see the [width()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics-obsolete.html#width) method which can give you the width of a given QString.

```
QFont myFont(fontName, fontSize);;
QString str("I wonder how wide this is?");

QFontMetrics fm(myFont);
int width=fm.width(str);
```

Answer (score 17):

In the paintEvent

```
QString text("text");
QFontMetrics fm = painter.fontMetrics();
int width = fm.width(text);
```

Answer (score 7):

As an addition to the answer by @Paul, I found that when painting text (Qt4.8 on linux), the width of an actually painted text compared to the width of what `QFontMetrics::boundingRect` returns is often off. In my cases, the painting was often too wide.

If you want accurate results when painting text (for example to dimension rectangles you draw around text), better use the `boundingRect` functions provided directly by `QPainter`.

Comment: Found the same situation on OS X with Qt 5.5.1. The height was off. I was using a standalone QFontMetrics but needed to set the font on the painter and use its boundingRect directly to accurately measure the text.