# How to limit QPushButton from bieng smaller then the size of its text?

Tags: qt

Unexpectedly for myself I found out that buttons impudently ignore the `size` of the text and easily cut it with a decrease.
Is there something like `sizeAdjustPolicy` as at `QComboBox`? If not, what is the correct decision?
In Google and other places I didn't find anything intelligible. 
Thanks in advance!
edit2:
I used `Qt Style Sheets`, cleaned - works fine. Have to give up beauty.

Solution: it was in Qt Style Sheets. If there to use `min-width` property then something spoils and the button ignores the text size.

Comment: If you wish to answer your own question, you should post an answer, and treat the answer like if it were to *someone else's question*. Thus, you should provide the necessary detail for someone else to use your answer with your question. Answers/questions that lack sufficient detail to be useful to others don't belong here.

Comment: It is not clear from your title and question whether you want to constrain the button not to be too large, or not to be too small. I presume you don't want it to get too small, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was in Qt Style Sheets. If there to use `min-width` property then something spoils and the button ignores the text size.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent a button from getting too small, set its horizontal size policy to `MinimumExpanding`. I don't see a reason to use stylesheets for that.

If you wish to manage the size of the button yourself, you can get the minimum size hint of any control by using the `minimumSizeHint` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337523/measuring-text-width-in-qt) question to determine the text size and set the button width according to it using [QFontMetrics](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfontmetrics.html).

Comment: This ignores the styling. Font metrics are insufficient to determine how big a button needs to be.

Comment: I don't really see why they are insufficient. Of course there is some offset required to add to the text width but from your question, I understand you only want to adjust the width to the displayed text and so far I had no problem using QFontMetrics for that

Comment: The button already does all those calculations, why do it yet again?

Comment: Your suggestion is without a question better. But that does not mean that Font Metrics are wrong for that task, just not elegant.

Comment: To do what you claim you need to duplicate the size hint calculation code from `QPushButton`, and you need to make sure that you've got it right. If you had a look at that code, you'll realize that it's a lost case, it's not merely adding "some offset required". Qt controls have two sources of styling (the `QStyle` mechanism and style sheets), so it's not as simple as it seems. Why bother when `minimumSizeHint` provides precisely what you wish to manually recalculate?

Comment: Like I said, your approach is better. I did not know that this sizeHint exists and will surely use it from now on if I encounter such a problem. But I never had issues achieving a correct size using Font Metrics so far.